# How can I filter json data using Python?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to understand how to filter json data using Python
my json looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "comments_full": []
    },
    {
        "comments_full": [
            {
                "comment_id": "433934735000014",
                "comment_url": "https:\\/\\/facebook.com\\/433934735000014",
                "commenter_id": "100002886314120",
                "commenter_url": "https:\\/\\/facebook.com\\/loubnaharifi?fref=nf&rc=p&refid=52&__tn__=R",
                "commenter_name": "Loubna Harifi",
                "commenter_meta": null,
                "comment_text": "\\u00c0 18h \\u00e7a commence",
                "comment_time": 1636502400000,
                "comment_image": null,
                "comment_reactors": [
                    {
                        "name": "Bouygues Telecom",
                        "link": "https:\\/\\/facebook.com\\/bouyguestelecom\\/?fref=pb",
                        "type": "like"
                    }
                ],
                "comment_reactions": {
                    "like": 55,
                    "love": 12,
                    "haha": 4,
                    "wow": 1,
                    "sad": 1,
                    "angry": 4
                },
                "comment_reaction_count": 77,
                "replies": [
                    {
                        "comment_id": "433935588333262",
                        "comment_url": "https:\\/\\/facebook.com\\/433935588333262",
                        "commenter_id": "94533530492",
                        "commenter_url": "https:\\/\\/facebook.com\\/bouyguestelecom\\/?rc=p&refid=52&__tn__=%7ERR",
                        "commenter_name": "Bouygues Telecom",
                        "commenter_meta": null,
                        "comment_text": "Oui tout \\u00e0 fait ! RDV \\u00e0 18h \\ud83d\\ude42",
                        "comment_time": 1636502400000,
                        "comment_image": null,
                        "comment_reactors": [
                            {
                                "name": "Maryline Moss",
                                "link": "https:\\/\\/facebook.com\\/mary.poilue.92?fref=pb",
                                "type": "like"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Jess Robic",
                                "link": "https:\\/\\/facebook.com\\/JessicaRbc91?fref=pb",
                                "type": "like"
                            }
                        ],
                        "comment_reactions": {
                            "like": 55,
                            "love": 12,
                            "haha": 4,
                            "wow": 1,
                            "sad": 1,
                            "angry": 4
                        },
                        "comment_reaction_count": 77
                         ...
```

What I'm trying to extract is:

- comment_id
- commenter_name
- comment_text

Here is what I tried so far:

```
df_ori[["comments_full"]].to_excel(r'C:/Users/stefa/OneDrive/Bureau/Scrap website/Last test/Scrapped_FB.xlsx', index = None, header=True)

cSvFilePath = "C:/Users/stefa/OneDrive/Bureau/Scrap website/Last test/Scrapped_FB.csv"
jsonFilePath = "C:/Users/stefa/OneDrive/Bureau/Scrap website/Last test/Scrapped_FB.json"
# Read the CSV and add the data to a diction
data = {}
with open(cSvFilePath, encoding="cp437", errors='ignore') as csvFile:
   csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
  for csvRow in csvReader:
    hmid = csvRow["comment_text"]
    data[hmid] = csvRow

file = dataframe(data, columns= ['comments_full'])
file.to_json(r'C:/Users/stefa/OneDrive/Bureau/Scrap website/Last test/Scrapped_FB.json',orient='split')
```

Comment: Please post a valid `json` file  i.e use the correct parentheses instead of the `...` at the end. Also, what is the error/problem with your current code?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service. There are thousands and thousands of [questions on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+json) dealing with parsing JSON in Python and extracting data from it that you should read first before asking a new question. There are also thousands and thousands of [tutorial websites](https://www.google.com/search?q=json+tutorial+python) available dealing with this exact topic.

Answer (score -1):

You should use  the json module:

```
import json

jsonObj = json.load(YOUR FILE)

print(jsonObj["FIELD_YOU_WHANT"])
```